# Adding two columns in mysql distinguish the count of male and female

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add two new columns to my query to be able to get the count of males and females

```
SELECT adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techname AS TechName
    ,adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techmobile AS Mobile
    ,monthname(adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.calvdatealv) AS "Calving Month"
    ,count(adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.sex) AS "No of Calves"
FROM adggeth.reg01_maininfo
    INNER JOIN adggeth.lng02_maininfo ON adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techmobile = adggeth.lng02_maininfo.aitechid
    INNER JOIN adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets ON adggeth.lng02_maininfo.hh_id = adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.hh_id
        AND adggeth.lng02_maininfo.visitdate = adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.visitdate
GROUP BY adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techname
    ,adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techmobile
    ,monthname(adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.calvdatealv);
```

I need to count the number of my female and male calves where

`lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.sex` = `1` refers to male calves
`lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.sex` = `2` refers to female calves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found my answer

```
 SELECT 
    adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techname AS TechName,
    adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techmobile AS Mobile,
    MONTHNAME(
    adggeth.`serv00_rpt_calvdtls2`.`calvdatealv2`
    ) AS "Calving Month",
    COUNT(
    adggeth.`serv00_rpt_calvdtls2`.`sex2`
    ) AS "No of Calves",
    COUNT(
    IF (
    adggeth.serv00_rpt_calvdtls2.sex2 = 2,
    adggeth.serv00_rpt_calvdtls2.sex2,
    NULL
    )
    ) AS 'Femal Calf',
    COUNT(
    IF (
    adggeth.serv00_rpt_calvdtls2.sex2 = 1,
    adggeth.serv00_rpt_calvdtls2.sex2,
    NULL
    )
    ) AS 'Male Calf' 
    FROM
    adggeth.reg01_maininfo 
    INNER JOIN adggeth.`serv00_maininfo` 
    ON adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techmobile = adggeth.`serv00_maininfo`.`aitechid` 
    INNER JOIN adggeth.`serv00_rpt_calvdtls2` 
    ON adggeth.`serv00_maininfo`.`fid` = adggeth.`serv00_rpt_calvdtls2`.`fid` 
    AND adggeth.`serv00_maininfo`.`regdate` = adggeth.`serv00_rpt_calvdtls2`.`calvdatealv2` 
    GROUP BY adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techname,
    adggeth.reg01_maininfo.techmobile,
    MONTHNAME(
    adggeth.`serv00_rpt_calvdtls2`.`calvdatealv2`
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `count` call on a `case` expression that filters the calves according to their sex:

```
COUNT (CASE adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.sex WHEN 1 END) as "No of Male Calves",
COUNT (CASE adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.sex WHEN 2 END) as "No of Female Calves"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) aggregation with [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```
COUNT (IF(adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.sex = 1, 1, NULL) ) AS Male_Calves_Count,
COUNT (IF(adggeth.lng02_rpt_b_calvedets.sex = 2, 1, NULL) ) AS Female_Calves_Count,
```

Answer (score 0):

While COUNT will not count NULLs, and therefore it is possible to use some condition which returns NULL if it's not the value you're looking for, it's much simpler to use SUM instead. Boolean expressions in MySQL return 1 or 0, so you can add up their values directly.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(adggeth.serv00_rpt_calvdtls2.sex2 = 2) AS 'Female Calf', 
  SUM(adggeth.serv00_rpt_calvdtls2.sex2 = 1) AS 'Male Calf'
...
```